# How to preserve directory layout of public headers when generating macOS frameworks

Tags: macos, cmake, frameworks, ios-frameworks

I have a CMake project for a C++ library (current version, CMake v3.21) which I'm in the process of porting to macOS, and I'm looking into generating the library as a [OSX Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html).

So far I've followed CMake's documentation on [add_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/command/add_library.html?highlight=add_library), and added the `FRAMEWORK` property to the library target as per [CMake's documentation on its FRAMEWORK target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/prop_tgt/FRAMEWORK.html).  This seems to mostly work, except that header files exported as part of its `PUBLIC_HEADER` property have their directory structure stripped and flattened from the export.

To illustrate this problem, let's consider the following project tree:

```
include
└── A
    ├── A.hpp
    └── subA
        └── SubA.hpp
src
├── A.cpp
└── SubA.cpp
```

The following CMake project generates a OSX framework when compiled on macOS:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

project(libA LANGUAGES CXX)


set(a_INCLUDES
    include/A/A.hpp
    include/A/subA/SubA.hpp
)

set(a_SOURCES
    src/A.cpp
    src/SubA.cpp
)

add_library(a
    ${a_INCLUDES}
    ${a_SOURCES}
)

set_target_properties(a
    PROPERTIES
    FRAMEWORK YES
    PUBLIC_HEADER "${a_INCLUDES}"
)

target_include_directories(a
    PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
```

However, the resulting framework flattens the directory structure of the header files included in its `Headers`, as shown below:

```
build/a.framework
├── Headers -> Versions/Current/Headers
├── Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
├── Versions
│   ├── A
│   │   ├── Headers
│   │   │   ├── A.hpp
│   │   │   └── SubA.hpp
│   │   ├── Resources
│   │   │   └── Info.plist
│   │   └── a
│   └── Current -> A
└── a -> Versions/Current/a
```

So, here are my questions: does CMake suppport preserving the directory tree layout of public headers shipped as part of a OSX framework? If it does, what do we need to do in a project in order to ensure that the directory tree layout is preserved?

Answer (score 2):

While you would expect to have your public and private headers placed including their relative path under the `Headers` directory this is not the case as you experienced. The entire path components are stripped. The same applies to hierarchically structured resources in the `Resource` directory.

What you can do to achieve this is to set the `MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION` property on every single header using the `set_source_files_properties` command. The location is the path to the header plus a `Headers` prefix, e.g. `Headers/A` for your `A/A.hpp` header and `Headers/A/subA` for your `A/subA/SubA.hpp` header.

Typically projects use a small convenience function for this that strips unwanted prefixes and file names from the given headers and add the install prefix.

```
function(set_macosx_properties _file_prefixes _install_prefix _source_files)
  foreach(_file ${_source_files})
    get_filename_component(_loc "${_file}" DIRECTORY)
    foreach(_prefix ${_file_prefixes})
      string(REPLACE "${_prefix}" "" _loc "${_loc}")
    endforeach()
    set_source_files_properties(${_file} PROPERTIES MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION ${_install_prefix}${_loc})
  endforeach()
endfunction()
```

Dependent on how your header and resource files are give you would use it like this:

```
set_macosx_properties("include" "Headers" "${a_INCLUDES}")

set_macosx_properties("data" "Resources" "${a_RESOURCES}")
```